# Spring MVC Repository Factory

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, autowired

**Approach 1:**

Below are the two service classes which are using same 2 repositories.

```
@org.springframework.stereotype.Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private CounterRepository counterRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
}

@org.springframework.stereotype.Service(value = "projectService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private CounterRepository counterRepository;

    @Autowired
    private SessionRepository sessionRepository;
}
```

So in above classes, as you see that CounterRepository & SessionRepository are using two times each in UserServiceImpl & ProjectServiceImpl services.

Is this is correct approach or I can make One Factory Class and use it to get required repo.

**Approach 2:**

```
class RepoFactory{

@Autowired
private CounterRepository counterRepository;

@Autowired
private SessionRepository sessionRepository;

 public <T> T getRepo(Class<T> entityClass) {
    if (entityClass == CounterRepository .class) {
        return (T) appMessageRepository;
    } else if (entityClass == SessionRepository.class) {
        return (T) auditTrailRepository;
    }
 }
```

And I use like below

```
 @org.springframework.stereotype.Service(value = "userService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private RepoFactory repoFactory;

    public void someMethod(){
       repoFactory.getRepo(CounterRepository.class);
       .....
    }

    public void someMethod2(){
       repoFactory.getRepo(SessionRepository.class);
       .....
    }
}
 @org.springframework.stereotype.Service(value = "projectService")
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {

    @Autowired
    private RepoFactory repoFactory;

    public void someMethod(){
       repoFactory.getRepo(CounterRepository.class);
       .....
    }

    public void someMethod2(){
       repoFactory.getRepo(SessionRepository.class);
       .....
    }
}
```

Could you please help me out which approach is better according to performance and memory consumption.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't configure it explictly, all spring beans are `singleton`, it will not affect memory at all! http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes

The first approach is easy to go, recommended!!

The second approach is totally unnecessary, if you want to, you can always autowire `applicationContext` and use `applicationContext.getBean(Mybean.class)`

If you have to `save` some memory on application start, you can have a look at `@Lazy`, but from my point of view, it is also not necessary.